# how to read a csv file and display its contents in java translucent swing window?

Tags: java, swing, csv

I need to read the contents of a csv file using java and display it in a swing window.I am able to get the csv contents printed but i am not able to see the swing window. Also i wanted the contents to be printed in the translucent window. My code is this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Swing extends JFrame {
private JButton aButton = new JButton("I am a Button \n");
public Swing() {
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
    final int R = 250;
    final int G = 210;
    final int B = 220;
    Paint p = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(R, G, B, 0),
                            0.0f, getHeight(), new Color(R, G, B, 255), true);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setPaint(p);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45);
    g2d.setFont(font);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.drawString("Abcde",40,120); 
    g2d.drawString(line,150,200); 
    }
    }
    };
    setContentPane(panel);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(aButton);
    pack();
    }

    public void runn() {
    String csvFile = "D:\\Html1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String abc = "";
    try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while (br.ready()) {
      line = br.readLine();
      System.out.println(line);
      abc = line + "--";
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge
                = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported
                = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
        if (!isPerPixelTranslucencySupported) {
            System.out.println("Per-pixel translucency is not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        Swing gtw = new Swing();
        gtw.runn();
        gtw.setVisible(true);
       }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for displaying the CSV content.

Comment: Get the CSV output to work before trying to make a translucent window, one problem at a time...

Comment: Also, make use of an appropriate CSV library, like OpenCSV and save your self a lot of head aches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few fundamental flaws...

Let's start with the `main` method...

```
System.out.println("DStarting");
SwingIt swObj = new SwingIt();
swObj.runn();
```

Is pointless, because you then completely ignore it...

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    SwingIt gtw = new SwingIt();
    gtw.setVisible(true);
}
```

And the window which is shown on the screen is not the one you created and called `runn` on, which means it is basically invisible (no size or position)...

Instead of using `swingText` to initialise the window, you should use it's constructor, but speaking of `swingText`....

You create a `JTextField` called `jj` and then simply throw it away...

```
JTextField  jj=new JTextField();
jj.setText(txt);
add(new JTextField("Text"));
```

This means that the text you supply will never be shown on the screen...you seem to be having a hard time understanding object/variable references...

Anyway, you should throw away the `swingText` method and replace it with a class constructor, for example...

```
private JButton aButton = new JButton("I am a Button \n");
private JLabel label = new JLabel("Label \n");
private JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("Text area", 5, 5);
private JTextField jj = new JTextField(5);

public SwingIt() {
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("bbb");
            if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
                final int R = 250;
                final int G = 210;
                final int B = 220;
                Paint p = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(R, G, B, 0),
                        0.0f, getHeight(), new Color(R, G, B, 255), true);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setPaint(p);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        }
    };
    setContentPane(panel);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(aButton);
    add(label);
    add(ta);
    add(jj);
    pack();
}
```

This will now mean you need some way to set the text of the of the `jj` field, to this end, simply create a `setText` method, for example...

```
public void setText(String text) {
    jj.setText(text);
}
```

And call it from your `runn` method...

```
public void runn() {
    String csvFile = "D:\\Html1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String abc = "";
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while (br.ready()) {
            line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            abc = line + "--";
        }
        setText(abc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Back to the `main` method...get rid of the first `Swing` object creation and simply use the second one, making sure you call `runn` on it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge
            = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported
            = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);

    if (!isPerPixelTranslucencySupported) {
        System.out.println("Per-pixel translucency is not supported");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwingIt gtw = new SwingIt();
            gwt.runn();
            gtw.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

As has already been pointed out, you should be calling `super.paintComponent` in your `paintComponent` before doing any custom painting.  As of (at least) Java 1.4, the `Graphics` object passed to your `paintComponent` method is guaranteed to be an instance of `Graphics2D`, so `if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {` is pointless

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

You should also take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to understand how components are actually laid out in Swing

Because of it's nature a CSV file would be best represented within a `JTable`, take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details...

You might want to take a look at something like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in order to read your CSV file rather then trying to re-invent the wheel on what is already a very complex problem...

Comment: I do not need text area and text box. I simply need to display the csv content in the swing window. Also the screen should be locked when the window appears.After pressing the button only the window should close. I have created the csv using contents of a table in a web page. Can i display the table content directly in swing window without converting it to csv?

Comment: That's good, you better to it then.  You might also find [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) useful.  You could try using [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), but it only has limited HTML support, so beware

Comment: The swing window is created but i cannot open it and display contents of csv file in it...I followed the instructions.. and edited my code in the question.. still not working

Comment: There's not `setText` method in your example

Comment: It still did not work for me. I edited the code in my question again.I am not able to see the window and display the csv contents in it

Comment: I am able to see the button displayed. That's all. ?Not the window and the csv content in it......

Comment: Well, you're not setting the text anything can display it so you see the CSV.  Try removing the `pack` method from the constructor

Comment: Ok...How can i set csv text in the swing window?..Can I do it using drawString()?

Comment: Best not do, that's very low level and a lot of work.  If you just want to display the text then use a `JTextArea`, if you want to display the HTML, consider using a `JEditorPane` or if you want to display the structure, then use a `JTable`

Answer (score 1):

I observed some points in your code.

- You forget to call `super.paintComponent()` in overridden `paintComponent()` method.
- You are using `GridBagLayout` but not using `GridBagConstraints` when adding components.
- You are creating object of class `Swing` two times.

See *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)